# Starling - get touch event under another

Tags: actionscript-3, touch, starling-framework

I have 2 circle, both have touch listeners.
Some times one circle overlap the other in the stage and i want to trigger both listener but starling trigger only the circle in front.

How can i do?

My code

```
circle1.addEventListener(TouchEvent.TOUCH, touched1)
circle2.addEventListener(TouchEvent.TOUCH, touched2)
function touched1(e:TouchEvent):void{
  trace("hi1")
}
function touched2(e:TouchEvent):void{
  trace("hi2")
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of having two separate listeners, have only one listener for one parent object. And add these two circles in this parent object. To detect which target is touched then, use `e.target.name` like so:

```
var parentClip:Sprite = new Sprite();
parentClip.x = 150; // x position
parentClip.y = 150; // y position
parentClip.name = "parentClip"; //This is not required in your case

parentClip.addChild(circle1);
parentClip.addChild(circle2);

parentClip.addEventListener(TouchEvent.TOUCH, onTouched);

function onTouched(e:TouchEvent):void
{
     trace("circles parent is touched");
     trace("Hit: " + e.currentTarget.name);
     trace("Hit: " + e.target.name);
}
```

Comment: MouseEvent in Starling?

Comment: Oops? Sorry. I forgot about starling while writing answer. Thanks for pointing.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe detecting if the circles is in contact. Try with this:

```
circle1.addEventListener(TouchEvent.TOUCH, touched1)
circle2.addEventListener(TouchEvent.TOUCH, touched2)

function touched1(e:TouchEvent=null):void
{
    trace("hi1");

    if (circle1.getBounds(circle1.parent).intersects(circle2.getBounds(circle2.parent)) == true)
    {
        touched2();
    }
}

function touched2(e:TouchEvent=null):void
{
    trace("hi2")

    if (circle2.getBounds(circle2.parent).intersects(circle1.getBounds(circle1.parent)) == true)
    {
        touched1();
    }
}
```